# Is the vector field $F = \left( 3x^2\ln(z), 16y^7z^4, \dfrac{x^3}{z} + 8y^8z^3 \right)$ simply-connected?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields

My understanding is that a set is simply-connected if every closed curve in the set can be continuously contracted to a point without leaving the set.

In this case, we have the vector field $F = \left( 3x^2\ln(z), 16y^7z^4, \dfrac{x^3}{z} + 8y^8z^3 \right)$. However, it seems to me that this set isn't simply connected, since we have that $z > 0$? Given this restriction in the domain, wouldn't we have "holes"?

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this. If the set is simply-connected, then which part of my understanding of this concept is incorrect?

Comment: Simply-connected is a property about sets, not functions. So really you want to ask, is the domain of $F$ is simply connected? This can't be true due to the $\ln(z)$ term i.e $z \not = 0$.

Comment: @FaraadArmwood Oh, I see. Thanks for the clarification. Yes, that is probably what I'm trying to ask.

Comment: So the set isn't simply connected? And, therefore, the vector field is not conservative?

Comment: No, $F$ can still be conservative in it's domain.

Comment: @FaraadArmwood But how can the vector field be conservative if its domain is not simply connected? Isn't being simply-connected a requirement for a vector field to be conservative?

Comment: I'm so sorry, I'm tired. $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \{z=0\}$ is still simply connected, why? Just think about $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{y = 0\}$. You wouldn't be able to parametrize a curve in these domains which pass through the hyperplanes you've deleted. So we've only separated the space into it's upper and lower half which are simply connected.

Comment: @FaraadArmwood I don't understand how it can be simply-connected if there are holes in the domain?

Comment: There aren't any holes. If you want to argue that there is a curve which can't be shrunk to a point, notice that there is no continuous curve connecting points in the upper and lower regions because you don't have the $z = 0$ plane. If someone was to ask if the set $D = \{(x,y,z): z>0\} \cup \{(x,y,z): z<0\}$ has holes, what would you say?

Comment: @FaraadArmwood I think I understand what you're saying. Since the entire $z = 0$ plane is excluded from the domain, we cannot have a closed curve that goes through $z = 0$ in the first place. Therefore, since no closed curve that passes through $z = 0$ exists, all of the closed curves that exist are simply-connected.

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean.

Comment: @FaraadArmwood Ok. Thank you for the assistance. :)

Comment: A general note: DO NOT (yes I am yelling) rewrite the same edits if they are rejected the first time.